# Read from sqlserver and insert each line values to a table cell programmatically or from design

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

I am working on a Dotnetnuke module and i try to read the products i have in my sql server database.
I managed to read the data from the asp tools LinqDataSource and ive inserted them in listview etc. This is now what i need.

The ideal would be if i could read from database my table, and for each row on the db.table to dinamically create a asp:table cell in the design. The asp table ould be 4x5. so 4 columns and 5 rows, and each cell would include an image and the text i load from the database(the image wont load from db, its the same image for all products).

Also if there are more than 20 products then a 2nd page is created with the rest, and page navigation at the bottom.

[image]

this is the result i want.

I didnt try much programmatically as i dont really know how to start this. Only from design i tried a few things but they are like a listview so it doesnt help much.

Any ideas or suggestions people?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the interface of the picture i provided and made all products clickable, all this from the design view with a ListView.

You can ask if you want any details